# Problem with the installation of scikit multiflow

Tags: scikit-learn, scikit-multilearn

[image]When I try to install scikit-multiflow library into a virtual environment using pip in command prompt, I constantly get this issue because there is no file called 'numpy.distutils', despite installing numpy library and Microsoft Vedio Studio Installer with version 14.0 (17.0 installed). I also made a new venv, installed it, and followed the same steps, but I still had the same problem. Could you please solve this? However, other libraries, such as pandas and creme, are installed correctly. Could you kindly resolve the issue with downloading the Scikit Multiflow Library installation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, you should also have to install one more package:

```
pip install -U Cython
```

https://scikit-multiflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html